# How to avoid ValueError while converting text file to dictionary

Tags: python, file, dictionary

```
ABC|JOINED
DEF|ABSENT
GHI|ABSENT
JKL|JOINED
MNO|JOINED
PQR|ABSENT
STU|JOINED
VWX|JOINED
YZA|JOINED
ABC|JOINED
DEF|ABSENT
GHI|JOINED
JKL|JOINED
MNO|JOINED
PQR|ABSENT
STU|ABSENT
VWX|ABSENT
YZA|JOINED
ABC|JOINED
DEF|JOINED
GHI|JOINED
JKL|JOINED
MNO|JOINED
PQR|ABSENT
STU|JOINED
VWX|ABSENT
YZA|JOINED
```

This is my "studList.txt"

And this is my code. Why am I getting the result shown?

```
d={}
with open("studList.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        (name,status)=line.strip().split("|")
        d[name]=status
print(d)
```

> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: Did you print `line` to see what the problematic line? My guess is it's a blank line. `Add if not line.strip(): continue` before you split.

Comment: There's a line that doesn't contain a `|`, so `split` doesn't return two parts. Check if you have an empty line in your file.

Comment: You seem you have multiple lines of text with the same key values, so existing key/value pairs in your dict are going to be replaced. Maybe that's OK, just checking.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments have alluded, there's probably an issue with your data somewhere and the code that's currently in the question does work. Obviously the ideal solution is to remove this problem by fixing the process that generated the data but, for example, if it was manually generated, the better approach would be to validate your data and not just assume that it is correct. For example:

```
d = {}
with open(r"../../Downloads/studList.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        data = line.strip().split("|")
        if len(data) == 2:
            d[data[0]] = data[1]
print(d)
```

By catering for possibly incorrect data, you can guard against getting that ValueError.

Alternatively, if it is truly exceptional to find faulty data and you would want it ignored and logged, the alternative is to wrap the code in question is a `try`/`except` block, for example:

```
d = {}
with open("../../Downloads/studList.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        try:
            name, status = line.strip().split("|")
            d[name] = status
        except ValueError as ee:
            print(f"Invalid data detected: {ee}")
print(d)
```

both will skip any faulty records.

As noted in comments, you are assigning multiple values to the same keys so only the last of them will survive. Hopefully this is either the correct behaviour or is only the case for this dummy data. If your class might have two people with the same name, you'll need a different identifier. Final note is that the parentheses in `(name, status)` are redundant.